# AngularJS Filter: Hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, hex

I'm trying to apply a filter that takes a decimal input and outputs hexadecimal through an AngularJS filter. I'm unsure as to why the filter isn't applied. I've checked the conversion with sample data in the console, e.g. 10 --> a

Any advice? Thanks!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.filter('hex', function () {
  
  return function(input) {
    return (input).toString(16);
  };
});


app.controller('hexCtrl', ['$scope', 'hexFilter', function($scope, hexFilter) {
    // Initialize initial values.
    $scope.decimal = 0;

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hexCtrl">
  <p>This input takes decimal: <input type="text" ng-model="decimal"></p>
  <p>Returns a hexadecimal: {{ decimal | hex }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: make it to `type="number"` will ensure that value is in `number` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert input to a number before doing the conversion:

```
return Number(input).toString(16);
```

Comment: I see. I needed to add the Number constructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.) Try to plug it in to your App.Module.  Angular.module("MyApp"['hexFilter']).

2.) angular.module('hexFilter', []).filter('hex', function() {

//Code

}

It should work after those changes.  Refer to here for more documenation
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09